# Sending with jQuery ajax an object containing empty array fails

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax, express

I want to send, using jQuery Ajax PUT, to a Node.js express server an object like this: `{value: {tags: []}}` The problem is that in the express `app.put()` handler the `req.body.value` comes undefined. After some test I tend to blame jQuery, but I'm not sure. The only workaround I found is to change the empty array into an array with an impossible value that I remove in the server.
Here is the client:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>MWE empty array problem</title>
    <script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<button>Push me!</button>
<script>
$("button").on("click", () => {

    $.ajax("http://localhost:4321/", {

        // dataType: "json", // This does not change the result
        // contentType: 'application/json', // Also this does not change the result
        data: {value: {tags: []}},
        // data: {value: {tags: [""]}}, // This works, but it is not what I want
        // data: {value: {tags: [], dummy: ""}}, // This gives an undefined req.body.value.tags
        // data: {value: JSON.stringify({tags: []})}, // This gives an undefined req.body.value.tags
        method: "PUT"
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And the server:

```
"use strict";

// > Load required modules
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

// Initialize application
const app = express();

// PUT Updating document: the action is given as parameter
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // for parsing application/json
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true})); // for parsing application/x-www-form-urlencoded

app.put("/", function(req, res) {

    console.log(req.body.value.tags);

    res.sendStatus(200);
});

// > Serve static pages
app.use("/", express.static(__dirname));

// Start the server
app.listen(4321, () => console.log("Server running on port: 4321"));
```

Any idea?

Comment: If you check the request in the console, what is the exact data being sent in each case?

Comment: Forgive my ignorance: how can I see what has been sent? I can see the header in the Firefox console, but not the body

Comment: Ah ah! `$.param({value: {tags: []}}` returns an empty string. So it is jQuery the culpit. If I set "traditional" to true, it serializes the single level object only.

Comment: Well found. In that case I'd suggest hard-coding the JSON string instead of letting it be serialised internally by jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

That probably happens because [] equals 0 and so it states "Undefined"

I only found a [humourus Picture to describe it](https://javascriptwtf.com/assets/the-javascript-trinity.jpg)

The best way to solve this will probably be to check if reg.body.value equals null